# ¿Como darle valor a un dato tomado de un serializaArray y enviarlo por AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Tengo una `tabla` llamada `'individuos'`,tiene datos básicos como `(id, no.identificacion, nombre completo, depen_serial(INTEGER))` entre otros...

*(para evitar algún comentario 'erróneo', así es como esta estipulado::.. )*

`depen_serial` **NO es una foranea** por lo que de igual manera el individuo `pueda que dependa de un numero de serie o no...`

Dicho esto el problema es el siguiente, en mi formulario tengo un `input number (para digitar el serial)` ...si dejo este campo vacio `ajax` realiza un `serializeArray();` pero el php le arroja un error ya que esta tomando un dato complemetamente vacio y la base de datos como necesita recibir un entero no va a leer el campo vacio....

Por lo que deduje fue lo siguiente, si este individuo no va a tener un serial se debe enviar un dato `NULL` para que la base de datos lo lea y lo inserte correctamente.

Espero haber hecho entender y agradecería su colaboración.

Dejo el código para que sea un poco mas claro...ya que la idea que tuve fue validar que si el serializeArray(); en el depen_serial tomo un valor vació entonces que le agregue un `null` pero no sabría como enviarlo por `ajax...`

```
$('#form_individuo').submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();

        if(data[8].value === '')
        {
            var convertir_a_null = data[8].value = null;
        }       
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insert_individuo',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
            })
            .done(function(answer)
            {
                var result = $.parseJSON(answer);

                if(result.answer == 'true')
                {
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                }
            })  
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: pienso que el manejo del null tienes que hacerlo del lado del servidor.  Volver a como estaba antes, probar el caso que te genera error, imprimir exactamente qué recibe el servidor y poner ahí el condicional que reemplace la variable recibida con un null.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esa validación debería de ser del lado del servidor,porque del lado del cliente cualquier persona podría cambiar el valor tranquilamente antes de enviar,del lado del servidor podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
<br>
$depen_serial = $_POST['depen_serial'] ?? ' ';
<br>
o sino 
<br>
$depen_serial = $_POST['depen_serial'] ?? null;
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas hacer esa validación desde el lado del cliente, puedes hacerlo usando este librería Free llamada [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) es la que mas utilizo yo.

Simple de usar, digamos para tu caso:

Declaras tu Input Number:

```
<input type="text" name="anumb"   data-value-type="number"  value="1"/>
```

Y luego simplemente haces el  Submit con el Ajax Nativo:

```
var postVar = $('#myForm').serializeJSON();
$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    data: postVar
}).done(function(data, result){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Suerte!